# Get Option Value OnClick with No Class/ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an ecommerce website with 100 items. Each item has an item option (i.e. Small, Medium, Large). Each option has a value with an integer that identifies the option.

When the user clicks "Add to Cart," I need express that value as a variable. The problem is all of these items have the same exact class/id so I can't write an onclick function for each one.

How can I use jQuery to get the selected option value onclick without a class/id to identify it?

Basic structure of the item form:

```
<form>
    <label>First Item</label>
    <select>
        <option value="6432">Large</option>
        <option value="5332">Small</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value = "Add to Cart">
</form>
```

Here's a Fiddle that shows what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/cusygh4o/

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).prev('select').val());
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cusygh4o/1/

*Note*: if there is *anything* you can do to narrow down that `'input[type="submit"]'` selector, you should.  For example, if you have a parent element with an id, you could do something like `'#shopping-items input[type="submit"]'`.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2q6ks5zL/)***

Just base it off where the click occurred.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parents("form").find("select").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedValue;
        $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        selectedValue=jQuery('form select').val();
        alert(selectedValue);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different ways to go about it: http://jsfiddle.net/cusygh4o/2/

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find('select').val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script>
        function getValue(e){
            value = e.closest('form').find('select').find(":selected").text();
            alert(value);
        }
</script>
```

Then replace all your `<input type="submit" value = "Add to Cart">` with `<input onclick="getValue($(this))" type="submit" value = "Add to Cart">`

Comment: This can be accomplished without altering the submit button's markup.